# More efficient way splitting than this?

Tags: java, regex

Is there a more efficient way of splitting a string than this?

```
String input = "=example>";
String[] split = input.split("=");
String[] split1 = split[1].split(">");
String result = split1[0];
```

The result would be "example".

Comment: Why do you need split in the first place, why not match a regular expression and use a group?

Comment: For your *given* example, even `substring` should work!

Comment: Just use String.replace("[=>]","")

Comment: Don't worry about efficiency, if you don't want to use substring because your String is not fixed, do it as you're doing it now. Don't complicate your life.

Comment: Need more examples to generalize a solution. Yes, this is not efficient. As Maroun points out, it's not going to melt your computer, probably ok to leave it as-is, if its working(even if its 20 lines, CPUs are fast nowadays). If it's always the first and last characters you want to strip, and there's only going to be 1 thing to extract,  go with Suresh's solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
String result = input.replaceAll("[=>]", "");
```

Very simple regex!

To learn more, go to this link: [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

Comment: This is not regex. `replace` doesn't take regex.

Comment: Thanks. I'll use that for short strings! But what about strings that are several lines long?

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need regex. You can do:

```
String result = input.substring(1, input.length()-1);
```

Otherwise if you really have a case for regex then use *character class*:

```
String result = input.replaceAll("[=>]", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get example out of that do this:

```
input.substring(1, input.lastIndexOf(">"))
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `string` of yours defenitely constant format   use substring otherwise go fo regex

```
result = result.substring(1, result.length() - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it more elegant with RegEx groups:

```
String sourceString = "=example>";
// When matching, we can "mark" a part of the matched pattern with parentheses...
String patternString = "=(.*?)>";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(patternString);
Matcher m = p.matcher(sourceString);
m.find();
// ... and access it later
String result = m.group(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex: `".*?((?:[a-z][a-z]+))"`

But it would be better when you use something like this:

```
String result = input.substring(1, input.length()-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String result = input.replace("[\\W]", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too

```
    String input = "=example>";
    System.out.println(input.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{Nd}]", ""));
```

This will remove all non-words characters

Answer (score 0):

Regex would do the job perfectly, but just to add something new for future solutions you also could use a third party lib such as Guava from Google, it adds a lot of functionalities to your project and the [Splitter](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained#Splitter) is really helpful to solve something like you have.